# Which redirect, if Host does not match?

Tags: http, redirect

A http server which gets used in the intranet (not internet) has the name `foo`.

The server has a FQHN `foo.example.com`, but still a lot of users use the old name.

I want to write a middleware which redirects the browser the the long URL:

From `https://foo/bar` to `https://foo.example.com/bar`.

Which kind of redirect fits here?

- 301: permanent
- 302: temporary
- ... or something completely different?

Comment: Looks like it should be `301 Moved Permanently` if you want the users use the new name.

Comment: @shaochuancs if you write your comment as answer, then I can up-vote it.

Comment: Thanks @guettli, I've wrote the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the users use the new name, and gradually obsolete the old name, `301 Moved Permanently` is the right choice.

According to [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2):

> The 301 (Moved Permanently) status code indicates that the target
> resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future
> references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs.